# Are these gulp statements run in parallel or in series within Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, gulp

I'm trying to understand how Node decides what to run asynchronously (in parallel) and what to run synchronously (in series).

Coming from a synchronous JavaScript background I would expect the first statement below to run first, then only after it completes would node attempt to run the second statement.

Am I right in assuming this please?

```
// first statement
gulp.src('src/test-1.txt')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'));

// second statement
gulp.src('src/test-2.txt')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'));
```

Comment: Async does not mean parallel (multible threads/processes running at the same time). It just means that the exection happens async. Streams like used for copying divide the data that is processed into small chunks so in you example the copying might be _interleaved_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and No.

The first statement is always executed and completed before the second statement started. This always holds true just like most of the programming languages.

However the goal/task (copy 'src/test-1.txt' to 'dest/') of the first statement does not necessary complete before the goal/task of the second statement (copy 'src/test-2.txt' to 'dest/').

It is possible test-1.txt get copied first, then test-2.txt, or vice versa. It depends on the runtime, the OS, the filesystem, the file size etc.

Also asynchronously have nothing to do with parallelism.
Execute code asynchronously means you enqueue tasks to a queue and yo don't wait until it finish before the statement complete (e.g. `setTimeout`). The tasks may be executed in serial or concurrently (mostly likely in serial for JS).

Whereas execute synchronously simply means you wait until the task finish before complete the statement.

Parallelism means you execute tasks concurrently (i.e. with threads).

Comment: I see. So the code executes one line after the other (as expected) but the result of each execution may return at a different time. So if I wanted to ensure that the second statement only runs after the first statement is fully complete I'd need to implement some form of callback/series runner.

Comment: Yes. But before implement your own serial runner, checkout existing library first.

Comment: Yes, I've seen one or two libraries that can help in that regard.I have a follow up query but am not sure if I should use this comment to ask it, but just in case:

say I have a function that reads two text files and returns the two files concatinated together. Is it possible the returned result could execute before one of the files is read form the filesystem, meaning that the result would only contain one file rather than two, or is Node smart enough to know that all statements within the function should be completed before returning the result?

Comment: It all depends how it is implemented and the API you are using. You can enqueue task read file 1, enqueue task read file 2, wait for both, enqueue task concatenate files. Or enqueue task read file 1, enqueue task read file 2, enqueue task that whats for two previous tasks then concatenate files. In later case, the last statement is executed before file is read. If you need more clarification, feel free to post a new question with more details.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. Yes, I'll post a new question to clarify further.